# get Headers from inbound request - Angular

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers, user-agent

I'm trying to get the User Agent located in the headers from the inbound request, in this case is my URL for example `localhost:4200` (local server).

Another example will be :
go to github.com -> dev tool in your browser ->  network -> click on github then click on headers and you will see the info.

My code:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/', /* async = */ false);
request.send();
console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
```

I didn't see any User-Agent Header, because is in the request not in the response, maybe?

[image]

> for the scenario I'm working on, I **can't use** `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: Can you add more detail and code to the specific problem you're having?

Comment: @thenolin basically you go to github.com -> dev tool in your browser ->  network -> click on github then click on headers and you will see the info

Comment: Can you explain your situation a little better? What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to accomplish that? Just trying to wrap my head around the issue here

Comment: @thenolin see my updated question. I'm trying to acomplish this on a click of a button. I need to accomlish this becasue is one of our requirements for a project at work. What I want to accomplish is getting the User agent from the current URL

Comment: how is this related to angular?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo It's related because im doing it in an angular app and maybe there's a way to do it in angular no just vanillaJS, but if vanillaJS is the only option, then i'm fine with using that code